# C++: how to assign static array to a pointer inside a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct

I have C-code that I need to compile to C++ and need to minimally change it.

In C, the following works

```
typedef struct _type_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c[];
}type_t;

type_t var = {1,2,{1,2,3}};
```

But in C++11, it gives the error

> error: too many initializers for `int [0]`

But I cannot give `type_t.c` a constant size because it needs to work for any size array.

So I need to change the struct to

```
typedef struct _type_t
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int *c;
    }type_t;
```

But then I need to change

```
type_t var = {1,2,{1,2,3}};
```

to something else because current code gives the error

> error: braces around scalar initializer for type `int*`

Casting 3rd element to`(int[])` gives error

> error: taking address of temporary array

This is from [micropython, parse.c](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/a3dc1b1957d2c96d7c60c2c629c95077b03488a1/py/parse.c#L99):

```
#define DEF_RULE_NC(rule, kind, ...) static const rule_t rule_##rule = { RULE_##rule, kind, #rule, { __VA_ARGS__ } };
```

How do I initialize the array and assign it to `type_t.c` ?

Comment: gcc warns with your C code: "warning: initialization of a flexible array member [-Wpedantic]" ( gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 )

Comment: You need to know the size of `c` to do this. For example, it would have worked if `int c[];` was `int c[3];`

Comment: @DimChtz if it works in C, why can't it be done in C++?

Comment: @Adrian Why would it? C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: Does it work in C? Or is it UB?

Comment: @manni66 it definitely works in C; this is micropython code.

Comment: @Adrian - No, it doesn't work in C. It works under your previous compiler, which offered an extension. The C language specification **explicitly** forbids it.

Comment: @StoryTeller I guess you're right: [it's not allowed by C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27852112/4784683) but it works in gcc.

Answer (score 7):

Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
struct type_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::vector<int> c;
};

int main() {
    type_t var = { 1, 2, { 1, 2, 3 } };
}
```

Comment: That's not an option. I need to modify it as little as possible i.e. not introduce use of stl.

Comment: Sure it's an option. It's the preferred option.

Comment: then I have to modify all the code that uses `type_t`

Comment: @Adrian `std::vector` has `operator[]` overloaded, so you can, still, access the elements stored in a `std::vector`, as you would access array elements.

Comment: @Zinki I'd love to but I need to compile every file as C++

Comment: @Adrian then you'll need to accept that C++ is not C and there are things you will have to do differently than you did in C.

Answer (score 6):

In order to do this you need to make your array really static:

```
typedef struct _type_t
{
    int   a;
    int   b;
    int * c;
}type_t;

int items[3] = {1,2,3};
type_t var = {1,2, static_cast< int * >(items)};
```

Comment: Since this works, why isn't it possible to declare an array inside the `{}`?

Comment: @Adrian - Because C++ doesn't allow. You can't force the language to be something it's not.

Comment: This solution is much more in-line with the task of converting existing C code to C++ than the highest-voted one.

Comment: @Jeffrey - No offence to this answer, but how do you reckon this is more inline?

Comment: @StoryTeller this leaves the memory footprint of the object indentical to what it was before. There's a chance that somewhere lurks an access to _type_t.c typcasted to int*. Or a memcpy of _type_t assuming a specific size. Or complexity in addind std::vector. I've converted legacy codebase before and typically, the less of change the better. Even if you end-up up with hackish stuff like that.

Comment: @Jeffrey - To be perfectly honest, the way I see this, the proper conversion is to keep compiling this as C with extensions. Just wrap it tightly and snugly in a standard compliant hazmat suit of code, and leave it be.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't allow this statement expression. You may use lightweight `std::initialiser_list` to achieve the objective

```
#include <initializer_list>
typedef struct _type_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::initializer_list<int> c;
}type_t;

 type_t var = {1,2,{1,2,3,4}};
```

Comment: `initializer_list` doesn't offer `operator[]`. The OP won't be able to use it as a drop in replacement.

Comment: Story Teller : Yes it doesn't provide subscript and one has to use the iterator to traverse through it. But its very lightweight as compared to vector and depending upon one's requirement they may choose to use it

Comment: It's too lightweight I'm afraid. For one there's object lifetime considerations to think about. Is the member `c` going to prolong the life of the temporary array created from `{1, 2, 3, 4}`? I don't think it will. Since the OP also wants  a drop in replacement, it doesn't go towards helping here.

Comment: it's also not lightweight enough, there's no guarantee that such a type_t remains POD; so even if it were correct, you'd gain very little over std::vector

Comment: I guess the requirements of the function / program should decided what to choose. Its an option, may not be the best for every situation, but memory and complexity wise its definitely better than the vector because there is no requirement of growing it dynamically (As per the code above)

Answer (score 0):

yet another alternative might be

```
    ...
    int * c;
}type_t;

type_t var = {1,2, []{ static int x[] = {1,2,3}; return x; }() };
```

PS: yes, I know it's crazy, but it's somewhat more respectful of OP requirements ( it can be incorporated in a dropin replacement macro as given )