# Why `sizeof var` does not show true size?

Tags: gcc, avr-gcc

Suppose we use `avr-gcc` to compile code which has the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t bLength;
  uint8_t bDescriptorType;
  int16_t wString[];
} S_string_descriptor;
```

We initialize it globally like this:

```
const S_string_descriptor sn_desc PROGMEM = {
  1 + 1 + sizeof L"1234" - 2, 0x03, L"1234"
};
```

Let's check what is generated from it:

```
000000ac <__trampolines_end>:
  ac:   0a 03           fmul    r16, r18
  ae:   31 00           .word   0x0031  ; ????
  b0:   32 00           .word   0x0032  ; ????
  b2:   33 00           .word   0x0033  ; ????
  b4:   34 00           .word   0x0034  ; ????
        ...
```

So, indeed string content follows the first two elements of the structure, as required.

But if we try to check `sizeof sn_desc`, result is `2`.
Definition of the variable is done in compile-time, `sizeof` is also a compile-time operator. So, why `sizeof var` does not show true size of `var`? And where this behavior of the compiler (i.e., adding arbitrary data to a structure) is documented?

Comment: Related: [why static initialization of flexible array member work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852062/why-static-initialization-of-flexible-array-member-work). The C standard says that a flexible array member in a struct does not increase the size of the struct (aside from possibly adding some padding at the end) but gcc lets you initialize it anyway.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Please make this an answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`sn_desc` is a 2-byte pointer into flash. It is meant to be used with `LPM` et alia in order to retrieve the actual data. There is no way to get the actual size of this data; store it separately.