# Initialize nested variable array members

Tags: c, struct, flexible-array-member

```
typedef struct nestedStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char* name;
} nestedStruct;

typedef myStruct
{
    int count;
    nestedStruct myNestedStruct[];
}
```

I need to define flexible structure which would have number of nested structures in it and structures themselves. And then I need to explicitly initialize them like

```
myStruct realStruct
{
    2,
    { 1, 2, "name 1" },
    { 3, 4, "name 2" }
} realStruct;
```

There will be a number of applications using the structure at the width they need.

It is clear for me that this syntax is not correct, I can't find the right one, and [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=declarations-flexible-array-members) explicitly states it is not possible. Why?

Any suggestions how I can make a "bus" of data structures without separating them into number of pointers to be able to pass single pointer to such struct to the functions and these functions knowing the layout of these bus without additional parameters.

**Edit:**

this one works

```
myStruct realStruct
{
    2,
    {
        { 1, 2, "name 1" },
        { 3, 4, "name 2" }
    }
} realStruct;
```

but there's pedantic warning

```
warning: initialization of a flexible array member [-Wpedantic]
```

Well, warnings are there to let me know I may do something incorrectly. Is there a way to tell compiler this is what I actually want to do - without suppressing the warning at all?

**Solution:**

not that elegant I wanted to, but: replace array with the pointer to array.

```
typedef myStruct
{
    int count;
    nestedStruct* myNestedStruct;
} myStruct

nestedStruct myList[] =
{
    { 1, 2, "name 1" },
    { 3, 4, "name 2" }
}

myStruct realStruct
{
    2,
    myList
} realStruct;
```

Comment: You might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687671/how-to-initialize-a-structure-with-flexible-array-member Flexible array member needs explicit allocation before it can be assigned.

Comment: Have seen this, but it says rather how to do it differently than why it is not possible. And there's no sense to touch memory heap for objects with known size at the compile time. Hmmm however I initialize object, not define it...

Comment: Instead of rewriting what you've tried from memory, copy the real thing into the question so that not everyone else has to correct your mistakes.

Comment: It is not necessarily to allocate on heap. You can do tricks with static allocation too, for example by making it a part of union with some sufficiently large byte array. OTOH If as you say, the size is known in compile time, then why not make it fixed size array instead?

Comment: @EugeneSh. for one application size will be 2, for another may be 10, but layout will be the same - number of members, some other properties for the group, and members themselves in very specific struct format. I was hoping I can make a template for such a thing.

Comment: If these two different applications, just `#define` the size for each.

Comment: if you `printf("%d", sizeof(realStruct))` you will find the compiler has not allocated space for the array.  This is how the standard is written - section [https://rgambord.github.io/c99-doc/sections/6/7/2/1/index.html] (6.7.2.1.16)

Comment: @EugeneSh. imagine I set up a structure for electrical bus. The members are wires with their various properties. They are standard flex cables, with width of 10, 14, 20 and 40 wires. I want to describe such busses with such super-structure. And the same application to have several busses of different width described in the same standard way...

Comment: @DavidJones `printf("%zu", ...`

Comment: Once you correct the definition of the `myStruct` type, GCC and Clang support initialization of a static object (defined outside any function or with `static`) containing flexible array member. The syntax would be `myStruct x = { 2, { { 1, 2, "name 1" }, {3, 4, "name 2" } } };`. This is an extension to the C standard. They apparently do not support defining it with automatic storage duration (inside a function without `static`).

Answer (score 0):

Flexible array members were invented for dynamic memory allocation.

```
typedef struct nestedStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char* name;
} nestedStruct;

typedef struct myStruct
{
    size_t count;
    nestedStruct myNestedStruct[];
}myStruct;



myStruct *init(void)
{
    myStruct *str = malloc(sizeof(*str) + 2 * sizeof(str -> myNestedStruct[0]));
    if(str)
    {
        str -> count = 2;
        str -> myNestedStruct[0] = (nestedStruct){ 1, 2, "name 1" };
        str -> myNestedStruct[1] = (nestedStruct){ 3, 4, "name 2" };
    }
    return str;
}

myStruct *init1(size_t size, nestedStruct *initData)
{
    myStruct *str = malloc(sizeof(*str) + size * sizeof(str -> myNestedStruct[0]));
    if(str)
    {
        str -> count = size;
        memcpy(str -> myNestedStruct, initData, size * sizeof(*initData));
    }
    return str;
}

myStruct *add(myStruct *str, nestedStruct *data)
{
    size_t newsize = str ? str -> count + 1 : 1;
    str = realloc(str, sizeof(*str) + newsize * sizeof(str -> myNestedStruct[0]));
    if(str)
    {
        str -> count = newsize;
        str -> myNestedStruct[newsize - 1] = *data;
    }
    return str;
}


int main(void)
{
    myStruct *s1 = init();
    myStruct *s2 = init1(2, (nestedStruct[]){{ 1, 2, "name 1" },{ 3, 4, "name 2" }});

    myStruct *s3 = add(NULL, (nestedStruct[]){{ 1, 2, "name 1" }});
    /* yuo should check if those functions did not return NULL */
    myStruct *tmp = add(s3, &(nestedStruct){ 3, 4, "name 2" });
    if(tmp) s3 = tmp;

    free(s1);
    free(s2);
    free(s3);
}
```